# ruby on rails installation by kevin skogland of lynda.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install ruby on rails on my system according to the Kevin Skoglund video tutorial on lynda.com.

But when I get to the part where I will type into the command prompt this code

```
gem install json --platform= ruby
```

it keeps on giving me this error message:

> Unable to download data from http://rubygem.org/ - Errno:: ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. -SSL(underscore) connect< https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Can some one help me with a solution please?

Comment: Can you please format it? it looks messy!

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the same class!  I had this same issue and took me a good chunk of time to find a solution.  I have Mac OS 10.11

Here were my steps:

A. Opened Terminal to find out what version of Ruby I was running: ruby -v
B. Where it was located: which ruby

I went to ruby-lang.org to get the most updated version...I kept getting errors.  See below:

1. go to www.brew.sh
2. opened Terminal and typed in: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   3.$ brew install wget
3. This should have completed your installation of homebrew.
4. Get into your apps store and update Xcode to the newest Version.
5. You will need to install RVM (Ruby Version Manager) and to do this, head over to www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#laptop-script
6. disable documentation in Terminal by running: echo "gem: --no-document" >> ~/.gemrc
   8.If you want to install ruby on rails following this: 
   curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enable --rails
7. If you want to install just ruby: 
   curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enable --ruby
8. Once complete quit/relauch Terminal and type in: $ type rvm | head -1.
9. if Terminal returns with RVM IS A FUNCTION, then all should be good.
10. Just to check to make sure you have the most up to date ruby go ahead and type the following: $ ruby -v

    11. $ which ruby

Hope this helps you out!  If it doesn't I'm sure somebody will either correct me (always welcome as I am learning as well) or they can point you into a better direction!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following line in `Gemfile` :

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

If so, try changing that to :

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

I'm guessing that rubygems is rejecting your non HTTPS connection.